# Reading data from private repository

Tags: r, git, github, data-science

I have a group with two different private repositories and I want to read a file .Rdata from one of the repos.

I tried this. But is not working

```
library(repmis)

source_data("https://github.com/opetchey/RREEBES/raw/Beninca_development/Beninca_etal_2008_Nature/data/GLE_estimate.Rdata?raw=True")
```

//The url of the code above is an example, I put the url of my private repo.

Comment: Have you considered the idea that the data takes too long to source? probably you should give it like a minute or two. `source(your_url)` and `load(url(your_url))` these two will take a minute but will still work

Comment: *"But is not working"* ... what happens? Lag? Hang? Crash? If an error or warning, please provide the verbatim text of the error.

Comment: Sorry, the output is this```Error in download_data_intern(url = url, sha1 = sha1, temp_file = temp_file) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404).```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the repository is private, you will need some kind of authentication to access it.

Accessing the https url would probably require using a cookie, or some additional header. Look at the docs for your git library for http/https authentication.

You can also try to access it through ssh, which will most probably go through your system ssh settings, and for example use a configured ssh key for authentication.

Here are the github help pages for setting up ssh for github :

[Connecting to Github with SSH](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)